# Faraday's law of induction: why does the minus sign disappear in this calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

My professor calculated induced emf by using Faraday's law the following way:

> $$\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Theta}{dt} = \frac{d(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{A})}{dt} = BA\frac{\cos{\omega t}}{dt} = -\omega BA\sin{(\omega t)}$$

However, the minus sign disappears after the second "$=$" sign. This results in a sine-function in the end, with a minus sign in front of it. When I did the calculation, I ended up with no minus sign in front of the sine-function in the end, because I was always using the original formula.

Can anyone explain why the minus sign disappears after the second "$=$" sign? To me, it seems like this should not happen, and in turn, the end result should not have a minus sign in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would handle the signs as you suggest, not as your professor did. But, having said this, I wouldn't claim to be more correct than your professor. The reason is that various sign conventions are assumed in these equations…

The very first minus sign, which is (correctly) said to represent Lenz's law, does so by means of a sign convention: that the *sense* of the induced emf is such that a right handed screw turned in this sense would advance in the opposite *direction* from that of the inducing flux change through the coil.

Then again, in the dot product, how do we define the direction of the area vector? Remember that the coil plane has two normal vectors pointing in opposite directions. For consistency we'd again use a right hand screw rule. If we call one of the two rotation senses around the coil the 'positive' sense, then we'd choose the normal direction along which a right-handed screw would advance if turned in the positive sense.